# how can I use date variable while building the model?

Tags: machine-learning

[Please find github link for data set and its info.](https://github.com/TharunAudhimoolam/datascience.git)

I'm working on some bank data set where I need predict the customers who are willing to take the loan(Classification). Can I drop that date column or I need to consider that?

Comment: M not sure what type of dates you are referring to, e.g. The date column would make sense if its a Birth Date of the customer, as taking a loan would depend on the person age as well which is conveyed by its birth date. So simply asking should i drop date columns does not make sense. In ML it  is always important to consider the context related to column.

Comment: If it is other(date of taking loan, date of joining) than birth date, then it would not help predicting your model.

Comment: That part also you can not say for sure, consider the following feature/learning that your model can derive with date of loan taking and birth date, using these two feature in combined, the model can learn that at what age people prefer to take loan which it could not learn if date of taking loan is not present

Comment: It's not customer DOB. It's customer account open date.

Comment: Dates are in below format 3/23/2005
10/11/2008
4/26/2012
7/4/2008
12/29/2001
6/7/2001

Comment: A simple thought process if that can help, do you think, taking a loan from a bank depends on for how long the customer has account in that bank till today. For me it matters a lot, i.e. i would prefer to take loan from my old bank instead of taking loan from a bank i recently joined. It varies from person to person, and including this information in your database would help train the according to model wht majority of people prefer. So, this way yup , from my perspective it matters to include the date of joining ( if not directly, in some form it should be there)

Comment: @TharunAudhimoolam i would be able to suggest or comment if you can share your test data

Comment: Please let me know how can I use these date column. Can I make that date column as age of account from now in days or months. That is if customer is very old with good transactions then chance of giving loan is very high.

Comment: Can u share sample test data , as simply looking at one column and coming to conclusion dropping/keeping/usage is not possible, sometimes one column it self does not make more sense, but in combination with other columns it does? Or if you can not share the sample test data, i advise to atleast share all the date columns (besides this one). One request, if any answer is helpful, kindly upvote it ;)

Comment: @AnkurGoel I given github link. Please go through that.

Comment: @TharunAudhimoolam you can drop the date field if you want, as the dataset already contain the length of relationship in months, these fields are dependent and removing date should not affect the model.

Answer (score 0):

M not sure what type of dates you are referring to, e.g. The date column would make sense if its a Birth Date of the customer, as taking a loan would depend on the person age as well which is conveyed by its birth date. So simply asking should i drop date columns does not make sense. In ML it is always important to consider the context related to column